# joining tables with multiple selects

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, by my understanding, I need to construct a query inside another query using multiple selects.
This is main table containing all products:
**proddb**,

onrrnr column value is unique here

```
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+-----+-------+-------+
|  onrrnr  |  onr  | idnr |         prod          | qty | measx | measy |
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+-----+-------+-------+
| 30000001 | 30000 | 2868 | P444s-15Ar;15Ar       |  15 |   608 |   808 |
| 30000002 | 30000 | 2869 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar |  10 |   679 |  1905 |
| 30000003 | 30000 | 2870 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar |  15 |   679 |  1905 |
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+-----+-------+-------+
```

And here is packed products table:
**packlist**,
no unique values here in columns

```
+----------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
|  onrrnr  | rackid  | packed_qty |       timestamp       |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| 30000001 | A664    |         15 | "2018-05-23 21:35:16" |
| 30000002 | A664    |          4 | "2018-05-23 21:35:24" |
| 30000003 | A140510 |         14 | "2018-05-24 13:56:58" |
| 30000002 | A140510 |          6 | "2018-05-23 21:35:34" |
| 30000003 | A161209 |          1 | "2018-05-24 13:57:14" |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
```

The relationship between two tables is "onrrnr" column.
Front end user selects a date and gets all packed products on that day, also it must show how many products are unpacked due date (get by summing all packed same onrrnr before selected date).

I need a single query to get result, because i use fppdf to generate table based on mysql query.
Result must be like this when select date 2018-05-24: packed contains total packed this date and in parenthesis how many are unpacked (total ordered from proddb-total packed due date)

```
+------+-----------------------+--------+
| idnr |        product        | packed |
+------+-----------------------+--------+
| 2868 | P444s-15Ar;15Ar       | 0(0)   |
| 2869 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 0(0)   |
| 2870 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 15(0)  |
+------+-----------------------+--------+
```

and when select date 2018-05-23:

```
+------+-----------------------+--------+
| idnr |        product        | packed |
+------+-----------------------+--------+
| 2868 | P444s-15Ar;15Ar       | 15(0)  |
| 2869 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 10(0)  |
| 2870 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 0(15)  |
+------+-----------------------+--------+
```

pay attention to last row, due 2018-05-23 there are not packed any id2870 products, inicating that 15 are unpacked.

Is it even possible to get this result using only single query?
First problem what i'm facing is that i cannot get distinct idnr with correct packed qty.
Secondly I don't know how to get the sum of packed qty due selected date.
my query so far:

```
SELECT 
proddb.idnr,
CONCAT(sum(packlist.packed_qty),"\n(",proddb.qty-packlist.packed_qty,")") AS packed, 
prod as product
FROM proddb
JOIN packlist ON packlist.onrrnr=proddb.onrrnr 
WHERE proddb.onr="'.$_POST['ordNr'].'" 
AND date(packlist.timestamp)="'.$_POST['date'].'" 
GROUP BY 
proddb.idnr
```

Comment: Think about Group by, Left Join and use sum(Case when value is not null then 1 else 0 end) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some you can try to do.

1. use `Outer join` base on `proddb`
2. set `date` condition to `ON` clause from Where clause, otherwise you will miss some data by `onrrnr`,
3. `CASE WHEN` in `SUM` function to calculat totle amount.

Here is sample query from

```
SELECT idnr,
       prod,
      CONCAT(cnt,"\n(", qty - cnt,")") packed 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      p.idnr,
      p.prod,
      SUM(CASE WHEN pl.packed_qty IS NOT NULL THEN pl.packed_qty ELSE 0 END) cnt,
      p.qty
  FROM proddb p
  LEFT JOIN packlist pl ON pl.onrrnr=p.onrrnr and date(pl.timestamp) = '2018-05-23'
  GROUP BY 
      p.onrrnr,
      p.prod,
      p.qty
) t
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddd891/15)

In your question, you can try to use

```
SELECT idnr,
       prod,
       CONCAT(cnt,"\n(", qty - cnt,")") packed 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      p.idnr
      p.prod,
      SUM(CASE WHEN pl.packed_qty IS NOT NULL THEN pl.packed_qty ELSE 0 END) cnt,
      p.qty
  FROM proddb p
  LEFT JOIN packlist pl ON pl.onrrnr=p.onrrnr and date(packlist.timestamp)="'.$_POST['date'].'" 
  WHERE proddb.onr="'.$_POST['ordNr'].'" 
  GROUP BY 
      p.onrrnr,
      p.prod,
      p.qty
) t
```

**[Results] 2018-05-23**

```
| idnr |                  prod | packed |
|------|-----------------------|--------|
| 2868 |       P444s-15Ar;15Ar | 15(0) |
| 2869 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 10(0) |
| 2870 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 0(15) |
```

**[Results] 2018-05-24**

```
| idnr |                  prod | packed |
|------|-----------------------|--------|
| 2868 |       P444s-15Ar;15Ar | 0(15) |
| 2869 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 0(10) |
| 2870 | P4kar44skar-15Ar;15Ar | 15(0) |
```